# Program crashes at times while using free on a pointer which holds conditionally allocated memory

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

This is a simple code just to illustrate the issue I am dealing with.

If you give the input of **n = 3** and **enter the array elements as 1, 2 ,3** and **m= 0** the program crashes!!!

Why is it so?? The problem occurs due to the **last 2 lines involving the free()**

Now my question is why this thing is happening? The same program with the same input doesn't crash if the free statements are removed...

Please explain me. **Is it so that the conditional memory allocation is causing the said problem to occur??**  If so then why ?

I am not getting any cue, moreover free (NULL) shall not cause any error as far as I know, so the problem is caused when I am trying to free one of the allocated memory, especially **positive** in my input ...

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter elements into the array\n");
    int arr[n];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;)
    {
        printf("arr[%d] ? ",i);
        scanf("%d",(arr+i));
        if(i>0)
        {
            if(arr[i]<arr[i-1])
                continue;
            else
                i++;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    int m;
    printf("m ? ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    int j,flag=0;
    int *positive,*negative;
    int start,end;
    start=arr[0];
    end=arr[n-1];
    if(start<0 && end<0)
    {
        negative=(int*)calloc((start*-1),sizeof(int));
        positive=0;
    }
    else if(start<0 && end>0)
    {
        negative=(int*)calloc((start*-1),sizeof(int));
        positive=(int*)calloc(end,sizeof(int));
    }
    else if(start>=0 && end >0)
    {
        negative=0;
        positive=(int*)calloc(end,sizeof(int));  
    }
    int p=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
            p=-1;
        else
            p=i;
        if(arr[i]<0)
            negative[-arr[i]]=p;
        else
            positive[arr[i]]=p;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int num=m-arr[i];
        if(negative!=0 && num<0 && negative[-num])
        {
            if(negative[-num]==-1)
                j=0;
            else
                j=negative[-num];
            printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
            flag=1;
        }
        else if(positive!=0 && num>=0 && positive[num])
        {
            if(positive[num]==-1)
                j=0;
            else
                j=positive[num];
            printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
            flag=1;
        }
    }
    if(flag==0)
        printf("NO SUCH i j EXISTS\n");
    if(positive) free(positive);
    if(negative) free(negative);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output:

[image]

Comment: Are you going out of bounds of any of the arrays (dynamically allocated or not)? Are you dereferencing `positive` or `negative` even if they are `NULL`? Have you tried to step through the code line by line in a debugger to see that it behaves like it should?

Comment: FYI, you don't need `if(positive)` or `if(negative)`. `free()` does that check itself.

Comment: I did it to be more sure that free(NULL) doesn't cause error

Comment: Also, what happens if `end == 0`? Then your pointers will be uninitialized.

Comment: Can `end` be `0`? Your `if` and `else if` blocks only handle `end < 0` and `end > 0`, not `end == 0`.

Comment: Running the code in Valgrind should catch the problem. Unfortunately I don't have Valgrind installed on the system that I'm currently using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the input values you mention, you first do :

```
end=arr[n-1];
positive=(int*)calloc(end,sizeof(int));
```

Given that `n == 3` and `arr[n-1] == 3`, you allocate an array of 3 `int`s for `positive`.

In the very next loop, you then end up doing :

```
positive[arr[i]]=p;
```

which tries to overwrite `positive[3]` (when `i == n-1`). This is trying to write beyond the bounds of the array (valid indexes range from `0` to `2` only), and [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) ensues, meaning anything at all can happen after that point, including a crash.